# Draw line in Z Orientation By mouse In Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm a beginner in three.js, I want to draw lines by mouse in a grid plane, and when getting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key draw the line in **Z Orientation**.

For doing this I have this code, but I don't know how to draw a line in Z Orientation?
Here is the code that I find from [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/32203864311/).

As I understand It creates a plane and uses Raycaster for finding a position in plane.

```
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
var stats = initStats();

     /* Variables required for ground grid */
     var length = 200; /*Line length*/

     /* Scenes */ 
function initScene() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

}

     /* Camera */
function initCamera() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 200, 250);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

}

     /* Renderer */ 
function initRender() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

     /* Lighting */
function initLight() {

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    directionalLight.position.set(100, 300, 200);
    scene.add(directionalLight);

}

     /* Controller */
function initControls() {

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
             /* Other attributes default */

}

     /* Scene content */
function initContent() {

             var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();/* simple basic geometry */
             var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x808080});/* basic line material */

             var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(length, 10);/* plane width: 200, and height: 10 */
             var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xD9D9D9, side: THREE.DoubleSide});/* plane material */

             geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-length / 2, 0, 0)); /* Vertex (-100, 0, 0) */
             geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(length / 2, 0, 0)); /* Vertex (100, 0, 0) */

             /* Create line segments in a loop */
    for (var i = 0; i <= length / 10; i++){

                     /* Horizontal line segment */
        var lineX = new THREE.Line(geometry, lineMaterial);
        lineX.position.z = (i * 10) - length / 2;
        scene.add(lineX);

                     /* Vertical line segment */
        var lineY = new THREE.Line(geometry, lineMaterial);
        lineY.rotation.y = 0.5 * Math.PI;
        lineY.position.x = (i * 10) - length / 2;
        scene.add(lineY);

    }

             /* Create a bounding plane */
    var planeX_left = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    planeX_left.rotation.y = 0.5 * Math.PI;
    planeX_left.position.x = -length / 2;

    var planeX_right = planeX_left.clone();
    planeX_right.position.x = length / 2;

    var planeY_top = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    planeY_top.position.z = -length / 2;

    var planeY_bottom = planeY_top.clone();
    planeY_bottom.position.z = length / 2;

    scene.add(planeY_bottom);
    scene.add(planeY_top);
    scene.add(planeX_left);
    scene.add(planeX_right);

             /* Position of the four surrounding surfaces y-axis up 5 */
    scene.traverse(function (object) {

        if (object.isMesh){

            if (object.geometry.type === 'PlaneGeometry'){

                object.position.y = 5;

            }

        }

    });

}

     /* Get the intersection point where the ray intersects the plane */
function getIntersects(event) {

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
             /* Create a plane */
    var planeGround = new THREE.Plane(normal, 0);

             /* The position where a ray emitted from the camera is clicked by the mouse */
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

             /* Get rays */
    var ray = raycaster.ray;

             /* Calculate the object from the camera to the ray, there may be multiple objects, return an array, arranged according to the distance from the camera */
    var intersects = ray.intersectPlane(planeGround);

             /* return vector */
    return intersects;

}

var pointsArray = [];
var window_mouse = true;
     /* Mouse down event */
function onMouseDown(event) {

             /* Obtain the intersection point of the rays emitted by the camera and Plane*/
    var intersects = getIntersects(event);

             /* Store the 3D coordinates of the grid */
    var vector3_x, vector3_z;

             /* When the left mouse button is pressed, points and line segments are created */
    if (event.button === 0) {

        if (!window_mouse){

            window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);

                             /* Avoid repeated addition of events based on the windwo_mouse flag */
            window_mouse = true;

        }

                     /* Determine whether the intersection point is between x(-100, 100) and z(-100, 100) (plane) */
        if (Math.abs(intersects.x) < length / 2 && Math.abs(intersects.z) < length / 2){

                             /* If the intersection point is within the plane at this time, create points (Points) */
            var pointsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            pointsGeometry.vertices.push(intersects);

            var pointsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color:0xff0000, size: 3});
            var points = new THREE.Points(pointsGeometry, pointsMaterial);

            pointsArray.push(points);

                             /* Create a line segment */
            var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});

            if (pointsArray.length >= 2) {

                lineGeometry.vertices.push(pointsArray[0].geometry.vertices[0], pointsArray[1].geometry.vertices[0]);

                var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
                pointsArray.shift();
                scene.add(line);

            }

            scene.add(points);

        }

    }

             /* When the right mouse button is pressed, go back to the previous point and interrupt drawing */
    if (event.button === 2) {

        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);

                     /* After removing the event, set it to false in order to avoid repeated addition of the event */
        window_mouse = false;

                     /* The movement state of the line segment when the left mouse button is not clicked */
        if (scene.getObjectByName('line_move')) {

            scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName('line_move'));

                             /* Delete the elements in the array, otherwise redraw will link the previous point and then redraw*/
            pointsArray.shift();
        }
    }
}
     /* Mouse movement event */
function onMouseMove(event) {

    var intersects = getIntersects(event);

             /* Determine whether the intersection point is between x(-100, 100) and z(-100, 100) (plane) */
    if (Math.abs(intersects.x) < length / 2 && Math.abs(intersects.z) < length / 2) {

                     /* The movement state of the line segment when the left mouse button is not clicked */
        if (scene.getObjectByName('line_move')) {

            scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName('line_move'));

        }
                     /* Create a line segment */
        var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});

        if (pointsArray.length > 0){

            lineGeometry.vertices.push(pointsArray[0].geometry.vertices[0]);

            var mouseVector3 = new THREE.Vector3(intersects.x, 0, intersects.z);

            lineGeometry.vertices.push(mouseVector3);

            var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
            line.name = 'line_move';

            scene.add(line);

        }

    }

}

     /* Keyboard press event */
function onKeyDown(event) {

             /* ESC to go back to the previous step of drawing and end drawing */
    if (event.key === 'Escape'){

        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);

                     /* After removing the event, set it to false in order to avoid repeated addition of the mousemove event */
        window_mouse = false;

                     /* The movement state of the line segment when the left mouse button is not clicked */
        if (scene.getObjectByName('line_move')) {

            scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName('line_move'));

                             /* Delete the elements in the array, otherwise redrawing will link the previous point and then redraw */
            pointsArray.shift();

        }

        var length = scene.children.length - 1;
                     /* Follow the steps to remove points and first */
        if (scene.children[length].isLine || scene.children[length].isPoints){

            scene.children.pop();
            length = scene.children.length - 1;

                             /* Do not remove if the last item is not a line segment or point */
            if (!scene.children[length].isMesh) {

                scene.children.pop();

            }

        }

    }

}

     /* update data */ 
function update() {

    stats.update();
    controls.update();

}

     /* Performance plugin */
function initStats() {

    var stats = new Stats();

    stats.setMode(0);
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.right = '0px';

    document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);

    return stats;

}

     /* The window automatically adapts */
function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

     /* Cycle call */
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    update();

}

/* Initialization */
function init() {

             /* Compatibility judgment */
    //if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

    initScene();
    initCamera();
    initRender();
    initLight();
    initContent();
    initControls();

             /* Event monitoring */
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
             /* When using mousedown, you can determine the left and right mouse button clicks
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
             window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false); /* When using events, remove the previous on */

}

     /* Initial loading */
(function () {

    console.log('three start...');

    init();
    animate();

    console.log('three end...');

})();
```

and this is output :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you struggle?

Comment: I know that it takes position from the plane by Raycaster but the plane is 2d and it cant get z, I want when the user press `ctrl` key can just draw a line in z . for example a user could draw Cube by mouse.I don't know how should I do this and how get z value and right position

Comment: @Parisa.H.R your new raised point is `point + (normal * desired_height)`.